# Getting [object Object] again but doesn't seem to be model issue

Tags: mongodb, express, twig, mongoose-schema, swig-template

I am trying to figure out how to access the `author.id` for a model when using a for loop with swig/twig. All of the others print out just fine but the `ap.author.id` is the issue I have tried `ap.author.id`, `ap.author.id.type` and `ap.author.id.ref` just hoping it was like my issue before seen [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799344/getting-object-ojbect-when-looping-model-out) but it seems it is not model related far as I can tell. Also when I `console.log` out `aps` it shows all the documents and the path that makes sense would be `ap.author.id`. I am out of ideas, what am I missing?

Loop:

```
{%  for ap in aps  %}
  <tr>
   <td>{{ap.name}}</td>
   <td>{{ap.manufacturer}}</td>
   <td>{{ap.model}}</td>
   <td>{{ap.type}}</td>
   <td>{{ap.notes}}</td>
   <td>{{ap.author.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Model:

```
var accessPointsSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  type: {type: String},
  manufacturer: {type: String},
  model: {type: String},
  IPAdress: {type: String},
  MACAdress: {type: String},
  range: {type: Number()},
  bands: {type: String},
  channel: {type: Number},
  dateBought: {type: Date},
  PoE: {type: Boolean},
  assetNumber: {type: Number},
  warrantyExpiration: {type: Date},
  location: {type: String},
  notes: {type: String},
  author: {
      id: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "User"
      },
      email: String
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `console.log` author.id you get back an object that will contain the ID needed but you need to access it by doing `author._id` otherwise you will get the [object Object] error because it is trying to output an object into a string spot.